# PWA 2016 enterprise custom field - Project Health Formula Error

Tags: ms-project-2016

IIf([% Complete] = 100, "Completed", Switch(([Finish] - Date()) < 75%, "complete within 45 days of finish", ([Finish] - Date()) > 90%, "complete within 20 days of finish", ([Finish] - Date()) >= 0, "On Schedule", ([Finish] - Date()) >= 0, "Future Project"))

Yellow: less than 75% complete within 45 days of finish
Red: less than 90% complete within 20 days of finish
Blue: 100% complete
Green: achieving % complete targets
Black: Future Projects

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
IIf([Start]>Date(),"Black",IIf([% Complete]=100,"Blue",IIf([% Complete]<90 And ([Finish]-Date()<20),"Red",IIf([% Complete]<75 And ([Finish]-Date()<45),"Yellow","Green"))))
```

Change the text as necessary.